Convert JsonObject to a Java Object auto-generated by Avro schema
In my code, I have:
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

final JsonObject mdata = niceservice.nicemethod();

The nicemethod() returns the following JsonObject:
{
    "Customer": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    "AdditioanInfo": {
        "samplefield1": "sampleValue1",
        "samplefield2": "sampleValue2",
        "samplefield3": "sampleValue3",
        "SubAdditionalInfo": {
            "SubAdditionalInfo1": "SubAdditionalValue1",
            "SubAdditionalInfo2": "SubAdditionalValue2",
            "SubAdditionalInfo3": "SubAdditionalValue3",
            "SubSubInfo": {
                "SubSubInfo1" : "SubSubInfoValue1",
                "SubSubInfo2" : "SubSubInfoValue2",
                "SubSubInfo3" : "SubSubInfoValue3"
            }
        },
        "ExtraInfo": {
            "ExtraInfo1" : "Extravalue1",
            "ExtraInfo2" : "Extravalue2"
        }
    }
}

i have a avro schema file in the resource/meta-inf/avro folder. based on this schema file, a class is autogenerated when i execute mvn clean install command. (lets call this: class ModernCustomer)
the class ModernCustomer structure is identifical to the json above.
so i want to do dynamically initialize my customer class with values from the json returned by nicemethod()
So far, I have tried:
final ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

ModernCustomer objc = objMapper.readValue(mdata.toString(), ModernCustomer.class));

But I don't think this is the right way to do this as it doesn't do anything. Considering I am new to Java, please kindly educate me to the fullest on how to resolve this issue.
Note: Usage of 3rd party libraries might be limited due to my org policies.

Could you update your post to include your ModernCustomer class?

the ModernCustomer class is created by avro schema. i have updated the question accordingly. thanks you  @Mr.Polywhirl

I believe you are using ObjectMapper from jackson library.
So you could do something like -
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(mdata.toString()).iterator().next();

ModernCustomer modernCustomer = objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, ModernCustomer.class);

Also there should be no need to configure ObjectMapper as ModernCustomer is auto generated from avro schema so ideally there shouldn't be any case of unknown properties during Deserialization.
